# PHPUnit in Laravel error : Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (2)'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, phpunit

I am trying to run **PHPunit** test for visit('/') in LAravel 5  but it fails with this message below      :
(*my app is running in docker container http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html* )

```
    class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }


        public function providerAllUrisWithResponseCode()
    {
        return [
            ['/', 200],
            ['/thank', 200],
            ['/non-existing', 404],
        ];
    }

        public function testDisplayThankYou($value='')
    {
        $this->visit('/thankyou')
        ->see('Thank you!');
    }       


        public function testPageControllerGet()
    {
        $this->call('GET', '/');
    }
        public function testDisplayWelcome($value='')
    {
        $this->visit('/')
        ->see('Welcome');

    }
}
```

and I am **getting this error** .

```
        $vendor/bin/phpunit 
PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...F

Time: 24.01 seconds, Memory: 16.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) MyTest::testDisplayWelcome

A request to [http://localhost] failed. Received status code [500].

    ..vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:196

    ..vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:80
    ..vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:61
    .../www/tests/ExampleTest.php:16

    Caused by
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (2)' 
    in ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
```

My behat features passed ! 
My .env.* files look like :

```
.env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

.env.behat
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Also : If I remove or change DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  in .env.behat and I run behat it returns an error!

The line 50 in **Connector.php** says :

```
   public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
    {
**here it breaks**-->   $username = Arr::get($config, 'username');

        $password = Arr::get($config, 'password');

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $pdo = $this->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(
                $e, $dsn, $username, $password, $options
            );
        }

        return $pdo;
    }
```

For example when I run DB ::table('something')->get(); it's working fine.

Someone sees the problem?

Comment: Seems like an environment configuration issue, the DB_HOST must be set to `mysql` in the testing environment.

Comment: what if your DB_HOST in your .env is set to `localhost` not `mysql` ?

Comment: @Devon  is my testing environment the same as the Laravel app. environment?

Comment: @ishadif
My Laravel app is running in dockervel (docker container)http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html
and I needed to set DB_HOST=mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `.env.behat` you should use the `mysql` as you host name. It is link through docker with that name not 127.0.0.1.

    `.env.behat
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=mysql 
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=homestead
    DB_USERNAME=homestead
    DB_PASSWORD=secret`

Comment: I changed it ,and tried all combinatations  ,you can see I posted this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043467/phpunit-testing-fails-only-when-visiting-the-root-page-visit-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment63548754_38043467 and I don't know what's the problem.If u get it please help.