# PHPUnit testing FAILS ONLY when visiting the root page( visit('/') ) in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, phpunit

**I run Laravel applic ation in docker container [dockervel](http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html) and**

**the test**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware ;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations ;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions ;
use App\User1;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
     public function providerAllUrisWithResponseCode()
    {
        return [
            ['/', 200],
            ['/thank', 200],
            ['/non-existing', 404],
        ];
    }
    public function testDisplayThankYou($value='')
    {
        $this->visit('/thankyou')
        ->see('THank you!');

    }

    public function testNewUserRegistration()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
         ->type('Taylor', 'name')
         ->type('taylor@talor.com', 'email')         
         ->press('Register')
         ->seePageIs('/thankyou');
    }

    public function testPageControllerGet()
    {
        $this->call('GET', '/');
    }

    public function testPageControllerGettoThankYou()
    {
        $this->call('GET', 'thankyou');
    }

    public function testUser1ControllerPost()
    {
        $response= $this->call('POST', '/');
    }


}
```

**IT FAILS ONLY on method testNewUserRegistration when  $this->visit('/')  it says:**

```
There was 1 failure:

1) MyTest::testDisplayWelcome
A request to [http://localhost] failed. Received status code [500].

Caused by
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (2)' in ..vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
```

**Note:Can into database thru my app.**

**laravel.log:**

```
[2016-06-27 09:02:53] testing.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (2)' in ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(55): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'homestead', 'secret', Array)
#1 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=mysq...', Array, Array)
#2 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(61): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
#4 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(908): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#5 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(776): Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo()
#6 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(661): Illuminate\Database\Connection->reconnectIfMissingConnection()
#7 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(342): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#8 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1583): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#9 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1569): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#10 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(624): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#11 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(316): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#12 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(649): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
#13 ../app/Http/Controllers/PageController.php(14): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::all()
#14 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\PageController->home()
#15 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('home', Array)
#17 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\PageController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'home')
#18 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#23 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\PageController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'home')
#24 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'home')
#25 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#47 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#52 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#57 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#62 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#63 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#64 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#65 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#67 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#68 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#70 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#71 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(515): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#72 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->call('GET', 'http://localhos...', Array, Array, Array)
#73 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php(61): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->makeRequest('GET', '/')
#74 ../tests/MyTest.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->visit('/')
#75 [internal function]: MyTest->testNewUserRegistration()
#76 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(909): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(MyTest), Array)
#77 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(768): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#78 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(612): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#79 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(724): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(MyTest))
#80 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#81 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#82 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(440): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#83 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(149): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#84 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(100): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#85 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(47): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#86 {main}  
[2016-06-27 09:03:05] testing.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (2)' in ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(55): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'homestead', 'secret', Array)
#1 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=mysq...', Array, Array)
#2 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(61): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
#4 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(908): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#5 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(776): Illuminate\Database\Connection->getPdo()
#6 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(661): Illuminate\Database\Connection->reconnectIfMissingConnection()
#7 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(342): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#8 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1583): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#9 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1569): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#10 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(624): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#11 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(316): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#12 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(649): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
#13 ../app/Http/Controllers/PageController.php(14): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::all()
#14 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\PageController->home()
#15 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('home', Array)
#17 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\PageController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'home')
#18 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#23 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\PageController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'home')
#24 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'home')
#25 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#47 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#52 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#57 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#62 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#63 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#64 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#65 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#67 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#68 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#70 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#71 ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(515): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#72 ../tests/MyTest.php(47): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->call('GET', '/')
#73 [internal function]: MyTest->testPageControllerGet()
#74 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(909): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(MyTest), Array)
#75 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(768): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#76 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(612): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#77 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(724): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(MyTest))
#78 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#79 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#80 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(440): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#81 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(149): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#82 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(100): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#83 ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(47): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#84 {main}
```

My:
    **.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=mysql
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=homestead
    DB_USERNAME=homestead
    DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**config/database.php**

```
<?php
return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mysql'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],
    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
];
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>./app/Http/routes.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_HOST" value="mysql"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="homestead"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="secret"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

**Please help!**

Comment: you are receiving back a status code of `500`. Check your log to see what error was thrown.

Comment: @z3r0ck above updated with a log file.

Comment: `'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mysql'),`

Try changing the DB_HOST value in .env to `localhost`.

Comment: @z3r0ck The same is happening.

Comment: But when I change 
<env name="DB_HOST" value="localhost"/>  I get this 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' in /home/zagorka/Desktop/docker/dockervel/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55

Comment: Obviously it's a MySQL connection problem nothing to do with laravel.
Try resolving the connection issue first.

Could try changing the .env files DB_HOST value to localhost.
`DB_HOST=localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try an other version much easier. It is based in PHP 7 and is ready to run phpunit tests in one comand `dunit`

`$ dstop
    $ git checkout builder
    $ . ./aliases.sh
    $ dup
    $ dunit`

Comment: This helpedfor PhpUnits ! Thank you! But I'd like to know why it failed , because I get the same error in log when I run Behat ,the problem is here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109339/behat-mysql-connection-error-in-laravel5-pdoexceptionsqlstatehy000-2005

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 things happening in your code snippet.

The first thing is that you are defining the **host** as `mysql`, not the **driver** (which i think is the one you are trying to set). Try setting the environment variable `DB_CONNECTION` to `mysql` instead of `DB_HOST`.

The second thing is that you need to add the `DatabaseMigrations` trait to your test class, try adding this:

```
<?php

// Imports

class MyTest extends TestCase {

    use DatabaseMigrations; // This line
    ...

}
```

Without this your tests will probably fail as it will find the database, but it won't find any tables created inside it.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Best practice for testing is to either mock dependencies that need to communicate with the database, or use an in-memory database for your tests to separate them from your real database.

In order to separate your testing database from your real database, you could use the `sqlite` driver in memory. Just update your `sqlite` driver in your `database.php` file like this:

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix'   => '',
],
```

And use it as the `DB_CONNECTION` environment variable in your tests (modifying `phpunit.xml`):

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

Comment: Hm , when add the DatabaseMigration every test method sends an Error the same as above , because it tries to connect to database even if some of them don't need it.

Comment: the best practice here would probably be to either mock all your controller's dependencies that need to communicate with the database, or to use the `sqlite` driver with the database in memory, that way you don't have to worry about database access. I modified my answer with the sqlite configuration.

Comment: sqlite changes didn't help ,the same problem .

Answer (score 0):

try this:
see if `mysql` container is up:
`docker ps`
You should see a `mysql` container. If not then run `dstop` & `dup`